# The .svg in my header.php will not change size

Tags: svg, scale, header-files

I inherited this site and am trying to change the Logo.

I managed to paste new .svg in the place of the old one but the new one will not resize at all.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="auto" style="display: none">
    <symbol id="vestoj-logo">
        <title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
        <path d="M0,.19H3.29l1.21,4.08c.1,.34,.17,.85,.2,1.16h.08c.01-.35,.08-.79,.18-1.16L6.14,.19h3.29l-3.35,8.67H3.37L0,.19Z"/>
    <path d="M9.58,8.87V.19h5.85V2.57h-2.7v.81h2.46v2.28h-2.46v.83h2.78v2.38h-5.93Z"/>
    <path d="M21.6,2.96c-.38-.26-1.07-.65-1.77-.65-.17,0-.43,.03-.6,.16-.12,.09-.16,.18-.16,.31,0,.18,.03,.35,.51,.45l1,.22c.77,.17,1.22,.48,1.48,.74,.55,.53,.66,1.2,.66,1.72,0,.74-.2,1.43-.78,2.04-.49,.51-1.43,1.1-3.05,1.1-1.33,0-2.21-.38-2.95-.68l-.29-.12,.95-2.44,.34,.26c.33,.25,.99,.64,1.75,.64,.43,0,.61-.1,.68-.16,.14-.12,.17-.26,.17-.39,0-.08-.01-.21-.1-.3-.1-.1-.27-.14-.6-.21l-.77-.14c-.49-.09-1.03-.25-1.51-.74-.44-.46-.62-.98-.62-1.6,0-.81,.27-1.5,.84-2.07,.66-.68,1.64-1.12,3.02-1.12,.69,0,1.59,.12,2.64,.75l-.84,2.21Z"/>
    <path d="M24.36,8.87V2.94l-1.77,.08V.19h6.63V3.02l-1.77-.08v5.93h-3.09Z"/>
    <path d="M37.56,7.67c-.74,.75-1.95,1.39-3.6,1.39s-2.86-.64-3.6-1.39c-.68-.69-1.21-1.75-1.21-3.15s.53-2.44,1.21-3.13c.74-.75,1.95-1.39,3.6-1.39s2.86,.64,3.6,1.39c.68,.69,1.21,1.75,1.21,3.13s-.53,2.46-1.21,3.15Zm-4.73-4.43c-.31,.33-.49,.83-.49,1.3,0,.49,.18,.98,.49,1.29,.26,.26,.65,.44,1.13,.44s.87-.18,1.13-.44c.29-.29,.49-.74,.49-1.29s-.18-1-.49-1.3c-.23-.23-.61-.44-1.13-.44-.56,0-.92,.22-1.13,.44Z"/>
    <path d="M40.3,.19h3.09V6.24c0,.95-.44,1.59-.78,1.94-.57,.6-1.37,.88-2.17,.88-.6,0-1.43-.13-2.24-.7l-.35-.25,1.14-2.68,.06,.22c.05,.18,.17,.43,.29,.53,.09,.09,.22,.16,.4,.16,.16,0,.27-.05,.36-.16,.17-.19,.18-.51,.18-.64V.19Z"/>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

I tried changing the viewBox and the width= to other values but nothing changes.

Comment: The svg in your question will not display because it's a symbol with display none.  Change the symbol to a group, <g> and delete style="display: none". Also I would change the viewBox to `viewBox="0 -0.02 43.4 9.1"`

Comment: @enxaneta thanks for the help, your suggested changes indeed made the logo larger. They also made the large logo appear above the header box which is now still showing the small logo form before. I believe I have a lot to learn about coding websites.